# Scraping returns empty list indexes that aren't empty

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

I'm scraping data from a web page and when I load the data into a list of lists it looks like this

```
[['text', 'text', '', '', 'text', 'text']]
```

I'm trying to remove the empty strings from all the list and so far everything I've tried doesn't work.

```
results = []
for list in scrape_list:
    for item in scrape_list:
        if item != '':
            results.append(item)



OUTPUT: [['text', 'text', '', '', 'text', 'text']]



scrape_list1 = list(filter(None, scrape_list))
     OUTPUT: [['text', 'text', '', '', 'text', 'text']]``
```

I'm wondering if these indexes aren't actually empty strings and are holding a value. If anyone else has encountered this feel free to let me know what's going on because I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're iterating through `scrape_list` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo, I guess (as mentioned in the comments by [@chunjef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865401/chunjef)):

```
results = []
for lst in scrape_list:
    for item in lst:  # do NOT iterate through scrape_list here!!
        if item != '':
            results.append(item)
```

The single item in `scrape_list` is a `list` and definitely `!= ''`, so this inner list is appended to `results`, hence your output.  The nested nature of `scrape_list` also makes your filter statement fail. You can use

```
scrape_list1 = [s for l in scrape_list for s in filter(None, l)]
```

to get one flat list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure pythonic way, you can use nested list comprehension

```
[[y for y in x if y] for x in a]
```

On my computer, console looks like this

```
>>> a
[['text', 'text', '', '', 'text', 'text']]
>>> [[y for y in x if y] for x in a]
[['text', 'text', 'text', 'text']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @chunjef in comments, you are iterating through `scrape_list` twice. By the way, a more compact manner of doing this is

```
>>> ll = [['text', 'text', '', '', 'text', 'text']]
>>> results = [item for l in ll for item in l if item!='']
>>> results
['text', 'text', 'text', 'text']
```

Where `[item for l in ll for item in l if item!='']` both flattens your list `ll` and drops any `l`'s item if it is different from an empty string `''`